# Return result from multiple if statements

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm trying to use multiple actions in if statement. For example:

```
x <- 1

if (x == 1) {
   paste("First")
   1*1                    #multiple actions
 } else if (x == 2) { 
   paste("Second")
   2*2 } else {("Nothing")
 }

 [1] 1        #what I'm getting

 [2] "First"
      1       #what I want to get
```

In this case only the second part of the expressions was printed to the console.
Any ideas how can I run all actions between **if** and **else if** ?

Comment: maybe print instead of paste

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All statements are running as intended. The value of a statement is only printed to the console if all these conditions are true:

- The value isn't saved to a variable
- The value isn't `invisible`
- It's the result of the last statement in an expression
- R is running in interactive mode

The reason things sometimes print is to help people interactively exploring data in the command line. Instead of type `print(x)`, they can save a few keystrokes by just typing `x`. In summary, use `print` if you want to be sure it's printed:

```
x <- 1

if (x == 1) {
  print("First")
  print(1*1)
} else if (x == 2) {
  print("Second")
  print(2*2)
} else {
  invisible("Nothing")
}
# [1] "First"
# [1] 1
```

Comment: I mostly threw in `invisible("Nothing")` to show how the `invisible` function is an exception.  Seemed to fit the spirit, if not the intent.

Comment: I got my mistake! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `print` or `cat`:

```
getResult <- function(x = 1) {
    if (x == 1) {
        cat("First", 1 * 1, "\n")
    } else if (x == 2) { 
        print("Second")
        print(2 * 2)
    } else {
        cat("Nothing\n")
    }
}


getResult()
# First 1 

getResult(2)
# [1] "Second"
# [1] 4
```